# GCP Bigquery WORKDAY function

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

How do I go about calculating number of workdays in a MONTH based on a date in another column?

Example:
Column 1 - 2020-06-30
Column 2 (Calculated) - 22 (i.e number of workdays in the month of June Mon to Friday)

Does BQ have a WORKDAY function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below approach

```
create temp function workdays(input date) as (( 
  select count(*)
  from unnest(generate_date_array(date_trunc(input, month), last_day(input, month ))) day
  where not extract(dayofweek from day) in (1, 7)
));
select column1, 
  workdays(column1) as column2
from your_table
```

if applied to sample data in  your question - output is

[image]